# Runnable JAR with different configurations in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, configuration, jar, runnable

I'd like to create with NetBeans different runnable jars from the same sources, each with different "parameters". 
For this purpose i cannot simply use a .properties file  because I need to provide to each customer, his customized application.
How can I do it? Better with NetBeans (since I moved to it for development)

Comment: you could use ant script for this

Comment: if the configurations do not include details that must be secret to the other clients (including passwords), you can send as a command line parameter the name of the .properties to load from the jar. Put that in a .bat or .sh and ship it with your app. You could ever ship it with several main classes and launch only the one for your client.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on you project > Set Configuration > Customize

There you can click on new to create a new configuration.

Each configuration can have a different Main entry point, JVM parameters, arguments, ant build script...

Once you have several configurations setup, you can right click on your project > Set Configuration and choose which configuration is the active one.

Comment: So if I set some launch arguments from the "Run" tab, they will be used when launching the generated Jar too? I thought it was just for running from within the IDE.

Comment: no these are the arguments used by netbeans to run your project. You can't specificy the jvm arguments in the jar.

Comment: ok so from set configuration I can't do anything, just change the startup options for netbeans..

Comment: @kappa You can also change the ant script, which can (for example) create files or include specific files in the jar etc. What is it exactly that you try to customize? The command line options used when launching your jar?

Comment: I have to customize images shown around the application, labels and so on.. because each customer wants "his own application". Maybe i can just provide launch scripts (let's say .bat and/or .sh) with the correct arguments.. but i'd prefer they have the jar to double-click on.

Comment: @kappa Then you could include those images etc. in a resources folder within your jar. You can do that from an ant script. And you can have one specific ant script per configuration (for example the specific ant script can move the right files to a resources folder in the `-pre-compile` target).

Comment: I already have my files inside the jar.. and never used ant, so i'll learn something about it :)